# Salvage Motor From HDD Without Screws

Tags: hdd

I’ve searched everywhere and can’t seem to find how to salvage this motor from my wd10ears HDD. It seems most other HDDs have screws to take it out, but this one doesn’t. The centre screw is just round so that doesn’t get it out. If someone could let me know how to approach this, that would be great.

[image: Top View]

[image: Bottom View]

Thanks!

Comment: I believe these are pressed. I have had no success with it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I’ll maybe try with a hammer, nothing to lose.

Comment: Press fit bearing. Use a press to push it out. Aluminium has higher thermal expansion coefficient than steel so you can heat the aluminium to facilitate the process.

Comment: I suggest a 12" hacksaw rather than a junior hacksaw, it will be much faster...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vise might have more chance of success than a hammer. If you have (or can make) a cylinder to press in the proper spot. Image from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7-vBQOW5Ao)

[image]